# Why does transition opacity doesnt work with background images?

Tags: css-transitions, opacity

This is my full code. When you press the buttons the div class is changed with a different background and it should fade in smoothly instead it just appears. This doesnt happen if the background is a solid color (if transition set to ALL). Why is that?

```js
function changit(color) {
 document.getElementById('cont').classList = color;
}
```

```css
#cont {position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;display:block;}

#cont::before {
 opacity:0;
 width: 93%;
    height: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    content: "";
    display: block;
 transition: opacity 2s ease;
}

.red::before { opacity:1!important;background:url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg) no-repeat; }
.blue::before { opacity:1!important;background:url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24780fb6df85a943c7aea0402c843737?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat; }
.black::before { opacity:1!important;background: black; }
```

```html
<div id="cont">

</div>
<button onclick="changit('red');">make red</button>
<button onclick="changit('blue');">make blue</button>
<button onclick="changit('black');">make black</button>
```

is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18353274/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30457239/5468463, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55309310/5468463, etc?

Comment: thats for background color. Im using images.

Comment: The question is absolutely unclear. There is no sense in classe names neither in aims. I voted to close

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 things that you would want to do when you set the new image.

- reset the opacity to 0
- change the actual image and transition opacity back to 1.

you're setting the image just fine.
You're not resetting the opacity.
You can achieve this by

- removing the class
- triggering a reflow, and render the element with opacity:0
- applying a new class

I've added logic to your `changeit` function to remove the class and trigger the reflow.
I've also moved the 'transition' css rule to the other classes. so that when we remove a class, it will immediately snap to 0 opacity

```js
function changit(color) {
  // remove the old classs
  document.getElementById('cont').classList = ""
  // trigger a 'reflow' so the dom is updated
  document.getElementById('cont').offsetWidth;
  // apply the new class.
  document.getElementById('cont').classList = color;
}
```

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#cont::before {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 93%;
  height: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.red::before {
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg) no-repeat;
}

.blue::before {
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24780fb6df85a943c7aea0402c843737?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat;
}

.black::before {
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: opacity 2s ease;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">

</div>
<button onclick="changit('red');">make red</button>
<button onclick="changit('blue');">make blue</button>
<button onclick="changit('black');">make black</button>
```

## using an animation:

if your animation has a single name, it will not automatically reset the animation when changing a class.
you can work around this by defining separate animation names in css.

```js
function changit(color) {
  document.getElementById('cont').classList = color;
}
```

```css
#cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

#cont::before {
  width: 93%;
  height: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.red::before {
  animation: appear-red 1s;
  background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg) no-repeat;
}

.blue::before {
  animation: appear-blue 1s;
  background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24780fb6df85a943c7aea0402c843737?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG) no-repeat;
}

.black::before {
  animation: appear-black 1s;
  background: black;
}

@keyframes appear-red {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes appear-blue {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes appear-black {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">

</div>
<button onclick="changit('red');">make red</button>
<button onclick="changit('blue');">make blue</button>
<button onclick="changit('black');">make black</button>
```

Comment: Thats great but I wouldnt like to change the javascript code. Is there any css alternative? I tried with animation like this `@keyframes appear {
  0% {opacity(0);}
  100% {opacity(0.6);}
}` but it doesnt work either.

Comment: Sure, an animation can also be used, you would then have to restart the animation instead. [that has a similar approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element)

Comment: If you really don't want to touch the JS, you would have to define separate animations names in css.

Comment: one animation for each class name?

Comment: It is clear that the question is unclear. The OP should first clarify before expecting your time and efforts to write back and forth